# django markdown link pattern (regex)

Tags: regex, django

I am using django markdown-deux and it has a link patterns setting where I can define different words that it will match and link to someplace. It came with an example that works, but then I couldn't get my own simple example to work.

The example that works:

```
"link_patterns": [
            # Transform "Recipe 123" in a link.
            (re.compile(r"recipe\s+#?(\d+)\b", re.I),
             r"http://code.activestate.com/recipes/\1/"),
        ],
```

My example that doesn't work:

```
"link_patterns": [
            (re.compile(r"site", re.I),
             r"http://example.com"),
        ]
```

`re` always confuses me a bit, so I think it is something easy that I am missing.

Comment: You need to use a capturing group (a pair of unescaped `(...)`) and then a backreference (`\1`) to that submatch in the replacement.

Comment: I just tried this...(re.compile(r"(site)", re.I), r"http://\1/.com"), with no luck...How could I make that work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using django-markdown-deux and I had to copy the settings word for word from the example settings and see what I could manually delete first, the settings looked redundant at some points, so I had deleted some of them without thinking about it.

The deleted settings were causing something to happen behind the scenes.